# How to check if the provided cloud-bigtable project and instance IDs are valid?

Tags: bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

```
val connection = BigtableConfiguration.connect(projectID, instanceID)
val admin = connection.getAdmin
Try {
  admin.tableExists(TableName.valueOf(tableName)) match {
    case true => connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf(tableName))
    case false => throw new IllegalStateException("The requested table do not exist.")
  }
}
```

This code can check if the table exists for a valid project ID and instance ID. Otherwise it will error out. Is there any way to check if the project ID and instance ID are valid using bigtable HBase API? I couldn't find a method to do that.

Answer (score 1):

There's a class called `BigtableClusterUtilities` that will allow you to get back a cluster for a projectId and instanceId.  You can call `getClusters()` to check to make sure that there is indeed a cluster for that projectId and instanceId.

Comment: This still doesn't help to check if the project ID and instance ID are valid or not. Any call to `BigtableClusterUtilities` with invalid projectID ends up in a `RuntimeException`.

Comment: Can you please create an issue here with the details of the exception: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-client/issues?